# After clicking the button,its not fetching the id of my listview

Tags: java, android

I want to get the id of listview after selecting the button,but its not fetching the id,how to get id while clicking the button in listview of each row.

```
public void onPrayComplete(List<Application> data)
    {
        this.items = data;
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                pray = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pray);
                //Application bean1 = items.get(position);
                /*Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Application obj_itemDetails = (Application)o;
                showAlertView(obj_itemDetails+"");
                prayerid = obj_itemDetails.getId();*/

                Application bean1 = items.get(position);
                if (bean1.isSelected()) {
                    bean1.setSelected(false);
                    pray.setClickable(false);

                } else {
                    bean1.setSelected(true);
                    pray.setClickable(true);
                }




            }
        });
    }







    public void pray(View v) {
        StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
        //showAlertView(sb.toString().trim());
        for (Application bean1 : items) {

            if (bean1.isSelected()) {
                sb1.append("Id:");
                sb1.append((bean1.getId()));


            }


        }
        showAlertView(sb1.toString().trim());
        //praydata(Integer.parseInt(sb1.toString().trim()));

    }
```

I want to fetch only the id and it has to show in my listview,but its not getting the id from my listview,how to fetch only the if from listview

Comment: @7bluephoenix ya dude i removed object also eventhough is not working

Comment: pls edit my code and tell,it wil more clarrification for me@7bluephoenix

Comment: can you just post some diagrams about what you ACTUALLY WANT TO ACHIEVE. so that it'll be easier to help you out, coz from what you have posted and what you are asking is a big question for me!!!!
Screenshots of your activity and what you want to do actually!